# Regular Expression Select HTML tags except A

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex pattern to select all html tags except the anchor tag.

I have been toying with trying to tweek the following regex that I found [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx) but it is one of those patterns that makes my eyes bleed.  This pattern seems very thorough so I am hoping to week it to avoid anchor tags.

```
</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

Comment: You might find the answer here relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

You want to search, not validate tags, so use simple regex pattern `</?(?![aA]\b)\w+\b[^>]*>`

Comment: Thanks but it appears that referenced article discussed scenarios where this does not work for all cases.  The pattern I re-posted from the article appears to properly catch all scenarios of html tags.  The issue I am trying to solve is that I want it to skip all anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used the original pattern in my first post to select all html tags then looped through each of them leaving only the anchor tags.That pattern was more reliable than the other one suggested.
Thanks for helping.